# Can I use 2 different armor stand positions?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been working on a small "mod" with command blocks in bedrock edition like world edit.

I've set on a method to shorten the `/fill` command with a tool. When you equip the tool, it places an armor stand, and you place two in the area you want to fill with air. But here's where I'm stuck.

From a command block, I've tried to execute at the location of ***all*** armor stands by doing `/execute @e[type=armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~` in hopes to use both of their locations. I get the error `Failed to execute 'fill' as Armor Stand, Armor Stand`.

If you have any ideas, go for it!

Thank you!

-Bedrock User

Comment: You didn't tell the game what to actually fill it with. Also, `fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~` means just setting one single block, is that intended?

Comment: As FabianRoling said, the error comes from not specifying what block to fill